# How to minimize sliding menu after clicking an button

Tags: android

I'm using https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu this SlidingMenu. I have a simple problem, I want to slide the menu to the left side after clicking a button on the Slidemenu. I used the sample program from jfeinstein10 and changed it for my usage.

Here are pictures.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXR2z.jpg)

[image]

If you still have questions write them down pls. Thx for help.

```
public class AnmeldenFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
       ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_anmelden, container, false);
        return view;
   }
}
```

this is my Fragment and I want to close the Slide menu after return view. It shows the new Fragment but it dont close the slide menu.

Comment: the menu obj.toggle() will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `interface` to communicate between fragment and activity then try this method to toggle menu `menu.toggle();` [Complete Tutorial](http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-sliding-menu-like.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to SlidingMenu object.
Create method which will handle your action.

Example:

LeftMenuFragment.java:

```
    private void elementPressed(int position){
        if (getActivity() instanceof YourSlidingMenuActivity) {//check if fragment attached to correct Activity which extends SlidingMenuActivity
            YourSlidingMenuActivity activity = (YourSlidingMenuActivity) getActivity(); //cast your activity

            if (activity.getSlidingMenu().isMenuShowing()) { // check if menu is visible
                activity.toggle();//method to close/open 
            }
        }
        }
```